# How to make it work in order?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm little bit confused here in this register route.As you can see I'm performing some validation checks before sending data to db.

> First, I'm checking for empty fields in a form and after that I'm checking for username and email existence in records and In last password confirmation.
>   All these thing are working fine but due to the async behaviour of DB query app crashed everytime.

```
/* POST Register User  */
router.post('/register',function(req,res,next){

let user = req.body;
//checking for empty field in a form
for(let key in user){
    if(user[key] === ""){
        return next(mid.error("All fields are required to fill"));
    }
}

User.findOne({username:user.username})
    .exec(function(err,user){
        if(err){
            return next(mid.error("Something went wrong"));
        }
        if(user){
            return next(mid.error("Username already exist"));
        }
});

User.findOne({email:user.email})
    .exec(function(err,user){
        if(err){
            return next(mid.error("Something went wrong"));
        }
        if(user){
            return next(mid.error("Email already exist"));
        }
});

//matching password 
if(user.password !== user.confirm){
    return next(mid.error("Password not matched.Try again !"));
}

//save data in object
let userData = {
    username : user.username,
    email    : user.email,
    password : user.password
};

//save data in database

User.create(userData,function(err,user){
    if(err){
        return next(mid.error("Something went wrong.Try again !!!"));
    } else {
        req.session.userID = user._id;
        return res.redirect('/home');
    } 

});

});
```

Is there is any way to get rid from this ?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485800/waiting-for-multiple-callbacks-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the queries are `Asynchronous`.
In this case, both your `findOne` calls are being processed because the `findOne` calls itself are `Synchronous`, leading to your error when one of the query completes first and executes the callback. Your callback then returns and passes everything on to the next middleware.

You sould put everything you want to happen after your first Query finished into the callback. In this case:

```
User.findOne({username:user.username})
.exec(function(err, foundUser){
    if(err){
        return next(mid.error("Something went wrong"));
    }
    if(foundUser){
        return next(mid.error("Username already exist"));
    }
    User.findOne({email:user.email})
     .exec(function(err,foundUser){
       if(err){
           return next(mid.error("Something went wrong"));
       }
       if(foundUser){
           return next(mid.error("Email already exist"));
       }
       //HERE GOES ALL OTHER CODE THAT SHOULD HAPPEN AFTER THE QUERIES
   });
});
```

> Note that I renamed the `user` variable inside the callbacks so that it does not conflict with your `user` object used for the queries!

In the future, or for a more complicated usecase, I would recommend using `Promises` to avoid deeply nested callbacks like this.